# How to display data in datagridview with OO Programming style?

Tags: c#, oop

This is the code i create to display all the data on datagridview in my database, it work fine. But I wish to make it to Object-Oriented Programming, means this form is only used to call the method, and the method is created from other .cs file, but i have no idea where to start. Can teach me how to do this on OOProgramming style? thanks for help, appreciate it.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace PreviewRecord
{
 public partial class ViewPurchase : Form
 {
    OleDbConnection myConnection;
    OleDbDataAdapter adap;
    DataSet ds;

    public ViewPurchase(string aa)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label2.Text = aa;

    }

    private void ViewPurchase_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            myConnection = new OleDbConnection();
            myConnection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\DataEntry\DataEntry\Database\Purchase.accdb";
            myConnection.Open();
            adap = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + label2.Text, myConnection);
            ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            adap.Fill(ds, "Account_Records");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler", ex);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One really great place to start on your way to more solid, object-oriented design is to start considering how to *separate concerns* in the `ViewPurchase` form. At present, this class is responsible for a lot of things:

- connecting to a database
- fetching raw data using an open database connection
- filtering out data for presentation purposes
- presenting the filtered data
- closing the database connection when it's finished

By taking some of these responsibilities away from this class and put them into a new class, you'll be *de-coupling* the UI logic (your form class) from the business logic required to supply it with data. This splits the problem up into two distinct pieces that are easier to solve separately instead of worrying about everything at once. When you create this new business logic class, you can supply an instance of it to `ViewPurchase` when it's instantiated and simply call it like so to get your data:

```
private void ViewPurchase_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable myData = _dataRetriever.GetData();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = myData;
}
```

Note the instance variable `_dataRetriever` in my example above. This variable would ideally be populated in the `ViewPurchase` constructor and inherit an interface of some kind, so as to allow you to create unit tests in the future and test your individual classes in isolation. This is pretty much the whole concept behind *dependency injection*, another good practice in OOP. It might look a little something like this:

```
interface IDataRetriever
{
    DataTable GetData();
}

class DataRetriever : IDataRetriever
{
    public DataTable GetData()
    {
        // TODO: How do we get the data?
    }
}
```

```c#
public partial class ViewPurchase : Form
{
    readonly IDataRetriever _dataRetriever;

    public ViewPurchase(IDataRetriever dataRetriever, string aa)
    {
        _dataRetriever = dataRetriever;
        label2.Text = aa;
    }
}
```

I know this is probably a lot to take in if you're just wanting to cut your teeth on object-oriented design, but if you take your time and try to digest each piece of what I've presented here, I think you'll find you're already familiar with the core concepts -- it's really just learning new ways to put them together! All we're really doing here is creating small classes and *composing* a larger unit from them.

I hope this answer helps, and best of luck in learning object-oriented programming!

Answer (score 0):

By Object Oriented Programming Style you probably mean the use of a design pattern.

You should check the [Model-View-ViewModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) Pattern out.

In very simple words MVVM uses three files:

1. The View: a file that controls how the data is presented on screen, usually written in XAML for modern Windows apps
2. The Model: The 'entity' that you want to present, in this case you database management class
3. The View Model: Controls the connection between the view and the model. It usually hides the implementation details of the model and provides the view with all the data that it needs to present

Comment: Just pointing out that question is using `WinForms` not `WPF` so talking about `XAML` is not applicable.